# How to post non-ascii data to Campfire?

Tags: javascript, unicode, node.js, campfire

Here is a test Node.js application:

```
body = {
    "message": {
        "body": "hello", //it works
        // "body":"привет", //doesn't work
        "type":"TextMessage"
    }
};

body = JSON.stringify(body);

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + B64TOKEN,
    'Host': SUBDOMAIN + '.campfirenow.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length': body.length
}

opts = {
    host: SUBDOMAIN + '.campfirenow.com',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/room/' + TEST_ROOM + '/speak.json',
    headers: headers
}

request = require('https').request(opts, function(response) {
    var data;
    data = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        return data += chunk;
    });
    return response.on('end', function() {
        console.log("===== start responce");
        console.log(data);
        console.log("===== end responce");
    });
  });

request.end(body);
```

`body` map is what I want to send. And you can see that with `"hello"` it work (ie message posted to Campfire chat) but with `"привет"` as body - an error occurs... In the second case i've got long html response from Campfire... I think this can be solved if I can send `body` in unicode sequence string... Like this: `"body":"\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"` but how?

Comment: BTW - this works just fine from Python... So the problem within Node.js... Not the Campfire API.

Comment: With help of Campfire's support i've found that `'Content-Length': body.length` is fools me. If i put `'Content-Length': body.length + 7` here it works just fine. So... i'm not sure how to fix though...

Comment: P.S. Campfire's server receiver something like this BTW:  `{"message":{"body":"п?<80>иве?<82>","type":"TextMess`. So you can see - it's wrong and incomplete json string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm (and you) should do this, if you need to respond with utf-8:

```
body = JSON.stringify(body);
buf = new Buffer(body);

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + B64TOKEN,
    'Host': SUBDOMAIN + '.campfirenow.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length': buf.length
}
// ...
request.end(buf);
```

You need to use Buffer. This way it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hej request.end takes a encoding argument
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/streams.html

set it to something supporting your characters.

Comment: It doesn't work. I need `utf8` but encoding argument is default to `'utf8'` already... so setting it doesn't help.

Comment: i wrote your characters to a local file an it works fine. im looking for a website to test it agents but it should work the same

Comment: Think you need to test it against Campfire. They have free account.